# Multiple Keys press Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game were there is this little robot that shoots. The problem is that it shoots only when it's not moving, when I move left or right or when I jump it doesn't shoot. Is there something that I can do for let my barspace key works when I'm pressing the other keys? I tried to put another if key statement in a key statement that already exist but it doesn't work, like this I mean:

```
elif keys[py.K_LEFT] and man.x >= 0:
    man.x -= man.vel
    man.right = False
    man.left = True
    man.standing = False
    man.idlecount = 0
    man.direction = -1

    if keys [py.K_SPACE] and shootloop == 0:
        if man.left:
            facing = -1

        elif man.right:
            facing = 1

        if len(bullets) < 5:
            man.standing = True
            man.shooting = True
            bullets.append(bulletss(round(man.x + man.lenght//2), round(man.y + man.lenght//2), facing))

        shootloop = 1
```

I left my github here so you can run the program. Thank you for the help and sorry for my code that is a mess.

https://github.com/20nicolas/Game.git

Comment: Please read the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page. The code you've posted here differs from the code in your repo and you also shouldn't post links to your project files because your code will most likely change and the links could get lost.

Comment: I also recommend posting your project on https://codereview.stackexchange.com to get some tips on how to simplify and beautify the code (you can add a link to your repo there).

Comment: How can I let the user try my program if I don't put my link for download the images too? Thanks for the codereview tip

Comment: It's recommended that the code should be reduced to a minimal, runnable example before you post it here. Of course you don't have to do that, but it would be nice since it saves us time. Images in pygame programs can usually be replaced by simple `pygame.Surface` instances filled with different colors.

Comment: A little tip: Use `smoothscale` instead of `scale` and the character will look a lot nicer. And convert the surfaces with [`convert`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) or `convert_alpha` to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if keys [py.K_SPACE] and shootloop == 0:` statement should not be inside of the `elif keys[py.K_LEFT] and man.x >= 0:` clause, otherwise you can only shoot when you press the left arrow key.

Also, in your repo it's actually,

```
if keys[py.K_RIGHT] and man.x <= 700:
    # ...
elif keys[py.K_LEFT] and man.x >= 0:
    # ...       
elif keys [py.K_SPACE] and shootloop == 0:
```

which means that it will only be executed when neither `K_LEFT` nor `K_RIGHT` are pressed, because these statements are in the same `if`...`elif` sequence.

This version works for me:

```
elif keys[py.K_LEFT] and man.x >= 0:
    man.x -= man.vel
    man.right = False
    man.left = True
    man.standing = False
    man.idlecount = 0
    man.direction = -1
else:
    man.standing = True

if keys [py.K_SPACE] and shootloop == 0:
    if man.left:
        facing = -1

    elif man.right:
        facing = 1

    if len(bullets) < 5:
        man.standing = True
        man.shooting = True
        bullets.append(bulletss(round(man.x + man.lenght//2), round(man.y + man.lenght//2), 1))

    shootloop = 1
else:
    man.shooting = False
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why it works well except when I'm jumping and moving left at the same time?

Comment: I have the same problem and I think it has to do with hardware limitations of our keyboards [(key ghosting and jamming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_jamming_and_ghosting). It works fine when I use the left control key instead of space.